# How to chart two different pandas data frames into one chart on matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, bar-chart, multiple-columns

I have two separate sets of data using pandas:

```
>>> suicides_sex = suicides_russia.groupby("sex")["suicides_no"].sum()
>>> suicides_sex
sex
female    214330
male      995412
```

&

```
>>> suicides_age = suicides_russia.groupby("age") 
>>> ["suicides_no"].sum().sort_values()
>>> suicides_age
age
5-14 years       8840
75+ years       74211
15-24 years    148611
25-34 years    231187
55-74 years    267753
35-54 years    479140
```

I want to learn how to create either a double bar chart using `matplotlib` or two separate bar charts where I can separate each age group by gender.

How can I combine both sets of data to create either a single bar chart with double columns or two separate bar charts for each gender?

Answer (score 1):

You can use boolean masks to separate the data and then group by age as you did.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

suicide_male = suicide_russia.loc[suicide_russia['sex']=='male', :]
# now you basically have the same dataframe but for male only

suicide_male_age = suicides_male.groupby("age")["suicides_no"].sum()

plt.bar(height=suicide_male_age.values, x=np.arange(suicide_male_age.index))
plt.xticks(labels=suicide_male_age.index)
plt.show()
```

Then you can repeat the same for female. That is probably not the most efficient way of doing it, but it works.

Also, I assumed the 'age' column values are strings, so I put `np.arange` as x positions of the bars and the values themselves as xticks.

Hope it helps!